# Azure does not accept json format for routing in IoT hub

Tags: json, azure, azure-iot-hub

recently i made a post about my routing in azure not being accepted. I found out that it is related to the json format i use but i don't know why. Json validation tools say my json format is valid but Azure say's it's not when i test the routing.

My routing is supposed to filter at level="critical"

```
{
  "devicemessage": {
     "appProperties": {
       "processingPath": "<optional>",
       "verbose": "<optional>",
       "severity": "<optional>",
       "level":"critical",
       "testDevice": "<optional>"
     }
   }
}
```

This from the azure example is accepted :

My Json message in the following way:

```
{"guid":"f7410833-7a8c-485a-8cfd-89285fc04256",
"deviceName":"Bmp280Sensor",
"tempSensorValue":23.5826187,
"pressureSensorValue":101344.492,
"altitudeSensorValue":-1.42682791,
"measurementTime":"2017-02-24T02:45:13.5858506-08:00",
"measurename":"LightSensor",
"level":"critical"}
```

But when  i try to test that in the azure portal it says:

"The syntax of your device message is malformed."

Other checking tools accept my json format. Does anybody understand why my json message is not accepted by the azure iot hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a format issue.
You can try this:

```
{
  "devicemessage": {
     "appProperties": {
       "guid":"f7410833-7a8c-485a-8cfd-89285fc04256",
       "deviceName":"Bmp280Sensor",
       "tempSensorValue":23.5826187,
       "pressureSensorValue":101344.492,
       "altitudeSensorValue":-1.42682791,
       "measurementTime":"2017-02-24T02:45:13.5858506-08:00",
       "measurename":"LightSensor",
       "level":"critical"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes as displayed above i understood that but I don't seem to understand why Azure demands a format for it to work like that.

Comment: [Message routing conditions use the same query language as device twin queries and device jobs.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-hub-message-routing-enhances-device-telemetry-and-optimizes-iot-infrastructure-resources/)  You can reference [query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language), [device twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins) and [device jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs). I am afraid it is by designed for consistency.

Comment: Ok that's what I needed to find. As far as the question goes I did fix it already but this makes more sense :)

Comment: Does actually not work for me. Still getting the same error message.